# How to reduce the size of the equation

Tags: equations, fontsize, minipage

I wish to put two equations into one line using minipage, but they are too wide, any solution for reducing the size of the equation without removing words so that I can put into one line to reduce space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{equation}\label{paira}
\mathit{MyA(s)}{=}
\begin{cases}
\max\limits_{a\in \mathit{MAede(s)}}Respone{a}{\cdot}lprt{s'}
\ \ if\ P_s=true\\
\sum\limits_{a\in \mathit{MAde(s)}}p_a{\cdot}Respone{a}{\cdot}lprt{s'}
 \ otherwise\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{equation}\label{pairc}
\mathit{MyC(s)}{=}
\begin{cases}
\min\limits_{a\in \mathit{MAede(s)}}costdd{a}{+}lprt{s'}
\ \ if\ P_s=true)\\
\sum\limits_{a\in \mathit{MAede(s)}}p_a{\cdot}(costdd{a}{+}lprt{s'})
\emph{ otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, you can't fit two trucks into two city car parking slots. I mean, if the equation can't fit in, they won't fit in, whatever you do. What exactly is the reason why you put them aside?

Comment: At first use the `\mathclap` command of the package `mathtools`, which is recommanded to load in you use amsmath. Put your limits in mathclap: `\max\limits_{\mathclap{a b c d e f}}`

Comment: You should write the whole thing as pseudocode instead. I can't help, as I do not understand the equations. What do you want to explain here? How shall the reader understand a formula which mixes, math, mathit, and emph letters?

Answer (score 1):

First I tried to translate it back to something readable with some guessing, what might be intended. Lots of curly braces are removed. For example, TeX's math spacing around binary and relational operators is lost, if they are put into curly braces. These braces form a subformula which is treated by TeX as ordinary math atom without additional spacing as a binary or relational operator. Text and text like variables are set via `\text`. Alignments are
used by using environment `align` and `cases`. Additional `\hrule` commands show the text width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\hrule
  \begin{align}
    \label{paira}
    \text{MyA}(s) &=
    \begin{cases}
      \max\limits_{a \in \text{MAede}(s)}
      \text{Respone}(a) \cdot \text{lprt}(s')
      & \text{if}\quad P_s = \text{true}\\
      \sum\limits_{a \in \text{MAde}(s)}
      p_a \cdot \text{Respone}(a) \cdot \text{lprt}(s')
      & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
  \\
    \label{pairc}
    \text{MyC}(s) &=
    \begin{cases}
    \min\limits_{a \in \text{MAede}(s)}
    \text{costdd}(a) + \text{lprt}(s')
    & \text{if}\quad P_s = \text{true}\\
    \sum\limits_{a \in \text{MAede}(s)}
    p_a \cdot (\text{costdd}(a) + \text{lprt}(s'))
    & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
  \end{align}
\hrule
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

As it can easily be seen, the equations take around 85% of the line width.
With some tricks, a width of an equation can indeed be reduced by some percents.
But shrinking an equation by around 40% is not sensible at all.

Comment: The original seems to be in a two column article.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably nothing that a typographer wouldn't have frowned at, but you can

1. allow the equation to extend into the margins by temporarily extending the width of the text,
2. reduce font size,
3. smash the condition under `\min`, `\max`, and `\sum`,
4. introduce shorthand notation just prior to the equation and rewrite your equation accordingly.